# Disable internet explorer error

Tags: javascript, http, internet-explorer-8

I am getting below error in IE8 
"Do you want to view the webpage content that was delivered securely"

To disable this error we need to set this option 
"Internet options -> Security -> Internet -> Custom -> Miscellaneous -> Display Mixed contents"

to enable

I am looking for a solution that can be done in code (probably javascript). Please tell me guys if have face any of such problem. The reason I am looking for a programmatic solution is because I cannot expect every user to enable this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your website to not embed any http:// resources on a https:// website. There is no other solution (except maybe not using HTTPS at all).

Actually, it would be very bad if scripts on a website could disable this warning. Mixed content can easily compromise the whole security provided by HTTPs e.g. when a script is loaded via http - it could be easily replaced e.g. through a MITM attack or DNS manipulation and then do anything with the website itself that was loaded securely.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable this security policy using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As @ThiefMaster said, this error is produced because you have a combination of things being fetched by both http:// and https://.

If all resources that you are currently serving via http:// can successfully be served via https:// instead, then you should change them all to do so.

Once they are all consistent, the error should go away.

A better way of referencing your URLs might be to use "protocol relative URLs" instead. This means that instead of "http://myserver.com/dir/resource.js" you use "//myserver.com/dir/resource.js" (i.e. remove the "http:" or "https:"). If you change all your URLs to that format (which is perfectly valid), then if the page itself is served over HTTP, then all resources (javascript, CSS, images, etc) will be served via HTTP as well. Likewise, if the page is served via HTTPS, then all resources will be served likewise. Again, make sure you can serve all resources this way first.